# Safari autofill does not fill the inputs on macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, password, keychain

I'm using M1 MacBook Air and Safari's keychain autofill is not working.
Prompts show up and Touch/Password authentication works, but still it is not filling anything in the text input fields of browsers, whether it's ID or password.

However Chrome is just working fine.
And on my iPhone too.

How can I fix this? Any guess on what's causing this issue?
Please help.

Comment: Does that happen on all sites or only certain sites on Safari? Has this issue recently started (assuming u have not recently acquired the MB Air) or has it been there for a while? Is autofill working fine on your iPhone with Safari or again only with Chrome?

Comment: @Alper It happens on every single site. I started using Safari about two months ago on my M1 Air, and I'm not sure how it used to be before. Autofill works fine on 1)Chrome on my MBA 2) Safari & Chrome on my iPhone. Safari on MBA is the only problem. I also tried updating to Monterey but with no avail.